# Default html file goDaddy Cpanel

Tags: html, .htaccess, directory

I have a simple html file name "Default.html" (as goDaddy preferred). I have also use .htaccess which contains **`DirectoryIndex Default.htm`**

Both of these files are in "public_html" folder.
The site only opens the page when i write `www.mysite.com/Default.htm` but it does not open this default page when i open this URL `www.mysite.com`.

Please Help , Thanks

Comment: What you've done is correct, did you clear your cache before testing?

Comment: @thickguru maybe .htaccess is off?

Comment: @William Unlikely as he is using GoDaddy for hosting. By default they initialise the `.htaccess` file. It's strange. This is at the top of your file right, Daniyal?

Comment: yes it is at top

Comment: i have tried every possible option , i am at deployment state and i need help :/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe .htaccess is off?  I'm not certain if I should try to help you edit the .htacess or something else.  Try changing the files name to `index.html` and also try `index.htm`.

That is the default index page often.  Last resort try `index.php`.

Comment: i have tried everything , index, default, Default,home

Comment: Godaddy has a live support line for stuff like this.